# Python in Ansys

Tags: ansys, ansys-apdl, pyansys

I'm using ansys.mapdl.core in addition to using an example from the documentation directly from the official ansys page, but I don't know why I can never go from this part, I already tried to convert it to str as the error says, but still no can.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDe6E.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNR5t.jpg)

I used exactly the example from the official website, and everything runs perfect except mapdl.k

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and [include a minimal code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question that others can copy replicate the problem you are having.

Comment: I tried running the [example code](https://mapdl.docs.pyansys.com/version/stable/user_guide/index.html#calling-mapdl-pythonically) and it works for me. I see you are using a Jupyter notebook, so I probably has something to do with a code snippet you ran before. Can you edit your question to include all the code you ran in order to recreate the error?

Answer (score 0):

Did you assign different id or coordinate to the same keypoint?
I think this might be the reason error happen.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35370171)